# JavaScript рандомно заполнить массив элементами из другого массива, чтобы элементы последнего повторялись не более двух раз

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, случайные-числа

```
prisvoitcvet();
function prisvoitcvet() {
    let allblock = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
    let arr = cvet();
    let k;
    console.log(allblock);
        for(k = 0; k < allblock.length; k++) {
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        allblock[k].style.background = arr[rand];
    }
}
```

В массив allblock я передал 16 квадратов, изображённых на картинке, а в массиве arr содержатся 8 рандомных цветов, которые вызывает функция cvet(). Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно каждому квадрату присваивать рандомный цвет из массива arr так, чтобы каждый его элемент повторялся не более 2 раз. Пока что додумался сделать только то, что у меня в коде, дальше никак...

[image: 16 квадратов передаваемых в массив allblock]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить такое решение.

Используем массив индексов, с длиной, равной количеству блоков. Из этого массива отбрасываем использованные индексы.

```js
// Генерируем массив цветов
function cvet() {
  let result=[
    "#5f9ea0",
    "#ff8c00",
    "#cd5c5c",
    "#32cd32",
    "#4169e1",
    "#663399",
    "#808000",
    "#fff0f5"
  ];
/*  
  for (const x of Array(8).keys()) {
    result.push('#' + (0x1000000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000)).toString(16).substr(1));
  }
*/  
  return result;
}

function prisvoitcvet() {
  let allblock = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
  let arr = cvet();

  //Каждый цвет встречается не более 2 раз
  let indexes = [...Array(8).keys(),...Array(8).keys()]

  for (let k = 0; k < allblock.length; k++) {
    //Случайно выбираем индекс из оставшихся в массиве индексов
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * indexes.length);
    //Определяем цвет
    allblock[k].style.background = arr[indexes[index]];
    //Отбрасываем использованный индекс
    indexes.splice(index,1);
  }
}

prisvoitcvet();
```

```css
td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
    <td class="block"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде всё просто, доступно, а самое главное работает... Но в первые вижу конструкцию [...Array().keys()], хоть и понял в чем её предназначение, просто хотел побольше почитать об этом, но найти информацию об этом не удалось... Причем, я ещё заметил, что Array.keys() - это уже другая конструкция, которая возвращает некий итератор, суть которого мне пока тоже не особо ясна. 
Не могли бы вы дать какую-нибудь ссылку или запрос, где бы я смог получить больше информации об этом?

Comment: @МаксимПравенький `...` - это spread operator. [Тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/348718/) хорошая статья. `Array(8).keys()` создает массив со значениями от 0 до 7

Answer (score 5):

Звучит так, что можно продублировать исходный массив, элементы перемешать и из получившегося массива брать последовательно элементы.

```js
let c = Array(8).fill(0).map((z, i) => `hsl(${i*33},55%,55%)`);
c = c.concat(c).sort(a => Math.random() - 0.5);
[...document.querySelectorAll('.w a')].forEach(b => b.style.backgroundColor = c.pop())
```

```css
.w {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 44px 44px 44px 44px;
  grid-template-rows: 44px 44px 44px 44px;
}
a {
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w"><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a>
</a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a></div>
```

В общем случае такой подход может быть опасен тем, что сортировка никогда не закончится, однако насколько мне известно в `js` у `Array` метод в методе `sort` реализована [сортировка слиянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)(merge sort) и проблем с зацикливанием быть не должно.

---

Еще Визуализация

```js
let c = Array(88).fill(0).map((z, i) => i - 44);

с = c.sort(a=>Math.random()-0.5)
update(c)
console.log(c.join(','))

function update(data) {
  d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("transition", "100ms")
    .attr('d', 'M0,-22v22')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${i*3},0) rotate(${d})`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="-10 -25 300 50"></svg>
```

---

PS: перемешивать в массивы лучше при помощи алгоритма [Кнута - Фишера - Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0) современная версия которого реализована, например в D3.JS в модуле [d3.array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) и представлен методом `d3.shuffle`

---

Вот вариант похожего алгоритма, не оптимальный по времени из-за используемых методов, зато лаконичный

```
let shuffle = c => {
  for (var i = c.length; i > -1; i--)
    c.push(c.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*i), 1));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let c0 = Array(88).fill(0).map((z, i) => i - 44);
let c1 = [...c0];

d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(c0)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr('d', 'M0,-22v22')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${c0.indexOf(d)*3},0) rotate(${d})`);


let i = c1.length;
shuffle()

function shuffle(){
  if (i === -1)
      return 
  
  c0=[...c1]  
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
  c1.push(c1.splice(n, 1).pop());
  i--;

  d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll("path")
    .each(function(d){
      if(Math.abs(c0.indexOf(d)-c1.indexOf(d))>2){
        let line = d3.select(this);
        line.attr('stroke', 'red')
        setTimeout(()=>{
           line.attr('stroke', 'black')
        }, 500)
      }
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .attrTween('transform', d => {
          let x0 = c0.indexOf(d)*3;
          let x1 = c1.indexOf(d)*3;   
          return t => `translate(${x0+t*(x1-x0)},0) rotate(${d})`;
      })
    
    setTimeout(shuffle, 210)
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="-20 -25 300 50"></svg>
```

Comment: Снимаю шляпу перед глубокими теоретическими и практическими познаниями. Кстати, оказывается в своем ответе я реализовал Оригинальный метод Фишера-Йетса. :)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Все верно, в первом приближении он весьма прост, однако у него есть вариации :) держите плюсик :)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov если Вам интересно я добавил визуализацию