# Рандомно вытягивать элементы из ассоциативного массива

Tags: javascript

Создаю мини игру Блэк Джек мне нужно из ассоциативного массива выбрать рандомно 2 карты, карт должно быть 52 но это так, для примера. Должен в итоге получить 2 переменные. 1-я переменная с названием карты, 2-я с её числом, что-бы в будущем складывать. и так 2 раза (OneCardName,OneCardNum и 
TwoCardName,TwoCardNum)
В коде получилось только вывести весь массив.

```js
function cards() {
    let coloda = {
            heart1: 1,
            heart2: 2,
            heart3: 3,
            heart4: 4,
            heart5: 5,
            heart6: 6,
            heart7: 7,
            heart8: 8,
            heart9: 9,
            heart10: 10,
            heartJocker: 10,
            heartlady: 10,
            heartKing: 10,
            heartsAce: 10
    }

    var randCard = function (coloda) {
       var OneCardName,
       OneCardNum,
       TwoCardName,
       TwoCardNum;
       for (var i in coloda) {
            document.write(`Название карты: ${i} Значение этой карты ${coloda[i]} <br>`);
        }
    }
    randCard(coloda);
}

cards();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тасование Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)
[Реализованный алгоритм тасования](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/)
[Обозначения](https://ok-english.ru/kartochnyie-masti-na-angliyskom-suits/) [карт](https://academypoker.ru/mathematics/2000-skolko-kart-v-pokere.html)

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}


const suit = {
  'H': 'Hearts',
  'D': 'Diamonds',
  'C': 'Clubs',
  'S': 'Spades'
};

const value = {
  'T': 10,
  'J': 'Jack',
  'Q': 'Queen',
  'K': 'King',
  'A': 'Ace'
};

let origin_deck = [
  'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'CT', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CQ', 'CA',
  'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'HT', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HQ', 'HA',
  'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'ST', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SQ', 'SA',
  'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'DT', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DQ', 'DA'
];

let shuffled_deck = shuffle(origin_deck);

first_card = shuffled_deck.shift();
console.log(`Название карты: "${suit[first_card[0]]}". Значение этой карты "${value[first_card[1]] ? value[first_card[1]] : first_card[1]}".`);

second_card = shuffled_deck.shift();
console.log(`Название карты: "${suit[second_card[0]]}". Значение этой карты "${value[second_card[1]] ? value[second_card[1]] : second_card[1]}".`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Первый очевидный вариант:

Возьмите 2 разных случайных числа в диапазоне [0 - кол_во_карт_в_колоде), а затем возьмите элементы из массива ключей объекта `coloda` по этим индексам.

—-

Второй:

Перемешайте массив ключей случайным образом и возьмите 2 карты подряд.

```
let tossed = Object.keys(coloda).sort((a, b) => Math.random() > 0.5);
let card1 = tossed.pop();
let card2 = tossed.pop();
```

—-

В реальной жизни можно было бы применить [алгоритм тассования Кнута-Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)

[В этом ответе есть визуалилация работы подобного алгоритма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981116/188366)